# Maven Multimodul project in Eclipse and in SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, maven, multi-module

I have an existing project, MainProject. I want to convert it to a multimodule project. In Eclipse I created a parent modul, which is just a pom modul and another modul, Modul_1.

Then I moved my MainProject in parent file directory. (Actually i did not want to move in parent folder. unfortunately to make it possible that Main_project finds the parent modul, i must do that)

Works fine..
It looks like:

```
-->ParentModule
------>Mainproject
------>Modul_1
```

Modul_1 is only needed in jenkins. It means the programmers should only care about MainProject.

How should I check in the project in SVN? With the same file structure or can i check in independently in SVN?

Comment: Where are your poms?

My experience with Eclipse is that it doesn't like hierarchical projects very much.
It's easier to have a flat structure with the parent at the same level as the children, and your modules in the parent are <module>../child1</module>.
But I haven't tried that recently.

Answer (score 1):

if the mainproject doesn't refer to ParentModule, you could layout it like this :

```
-->ParentModule
-->MainProject
-->Modul_1
```

in parentmodule's pom.xml :

```
<modules>
  <module>../MainProject</module>
  <module>../Modul_1</module>
</modules>
```

for jekins, there are 2 ways to configure job :

1. checkout parent folder and point pom's location to ParentModule/pom.xml
2. checkout 3 svn locations to each folder for 3 projects and point pom to ParentModule/pom.xml

for eclipse , you can checkout only MainProject.